# Personal discount for each customer

Tags: magento-1.9, php, promotions

I am working on a project where i want to give personal discount for every customer.
I want to add a customer attribute where i will give the discount amount for every customer.
As example if a gave 30 to customer "John doe" then John doe will get a discount of fixed 30.

Can anyone please help me how to do that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you create observer and set final price for product.

observer event as below

```
       <catalog_product_get_final_price>
            <observers>
                <seta_discountprice_price_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>Namespace_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>setDiscount</method>
                </seta_discountprice_price_observer>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_get_final_price>
```

Observer code

```
 public function setDiscount($observer)
    {
        $event = $observer->getEvent();
        $product = $event->getProduct();

         //get Login customer

         if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerData = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();   
            $discount =  $customerData->getDiscount(); //here is your attribute instead of discount
         }
         $discountPrice = ($product->getPrice()*$discount)/100;

        // process percentage discounts only for simple products
        if ($product->getSuperProduct() && $product->getSuperProduct()->isConfigurable()) {
        } else {

            $product->setFinalPrice($discountPrice);
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Refere [link](http://shortbutsweetmagento.blogspot.in/2013/07/discount-per-product-in-magento.html) it is also useful to you

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will definitely try it now and let you know

Comment: This worked. Thank you very much for your help